# How to export and read .txt files using iPhone?

Tags: software-recommendation, iphone

I've some text files (a few thousand lines each) on my PC. How can I transfer them  to the iPhone so that I can do my reading on-the-go?

(Sure I could simply email them to myself, but I'm looking for a more convenient and less time-wasting solution.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution would be to use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) or [iCloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/) to hold/sync your notes and read them with a simple text editing or note taking app. I use [Byword](http://bywordapp.com/).

Comment: +1, using Dropbox this is extremely simple. Copy or move the files to somewhere under your Dropbox folder, wait a moment, and you're done. (Prerequisites: register + install Dropbox on computer & iPhone.)

Comment: Dropbox used to be so handy. They've not wrapped it in some sort of monetization strategy that is very unfriendly.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is using [Simplenote](http://itunes.apple.com/app/simplenote/id289429962?ign-mpt=uo=6&mt=8), and [Notational Velocity](http://notational.net).

Simplenote also has a web app at simplenoteapp.com.

These apps all automatically sync your notes and have great search features.  I've used this for the past couple of years to store all of my notes.

Comment: My vote goes towards simplenote.  If you subscribe to simplenote, you can also get dropbox note synchronization, which will make it trivial for you to use and access the notes across all your devices, computers, and browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/) will be the simplest, free solution. Within the Dropbox app you can view text files. No other app needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use Airdrop to send plain text (.txt) file and open in Notes.  This works if you are away from wi-fi for your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You could download an app which allows you to read transfer and read txt files on your iPhone.

For me, I use fileapp to read my txt files on my iPhone. Transferring is done via the usb cable.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a couple of solutions, in the end what most solutions lack is *readability* (each of my notes is 
~1k lines long so being able to easily read them is essential).

I ended up with:

1. Save the .txt as .pdf.
2. Add it to the iTunes library.
3. Sync the iTunes library with the iPhone.
4. Open using the iBooks App.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of free text editors you could use but I think the fastest way is to send this notes to your own email and open them from your iPhone.