# How to add file(s) to an iPad in offline mode and read it in an app

Tags: ios, ipad, filesystem, file-transfer

I would like to know if it is possible to add files to iPad (or iPhone), while offline, and be able to read those files in an iPad app.

Maybe this is possible by connecting the device to a computer? Or any other means?

PS: Need this functionality without jailbreak.

Comment: Different apps are for different things. Try Readdle's Documents 8 for offline reading of PDFs, Apple's Pages for editing Word documents and Pages documents offline, Amazon's Kindle app or iBooks for reading offline, Code Viewer (just search for it) for viewing all types of code offline, the Photos app for viewing photos and videos offline, iMovie for making movies offline, and a host of other apps for offline viewing of different file types. Also try Google Drive + saving for offline for anything GDrive can do offline.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201301)?
If you are talking about iBook and reading pdf files, this new OS X version use iCloud to sync your files on all devices and after syncing you can read them offline.

Comment: Well I need the ability to add more than just pdf file type. Like JSON or XML or just general text files... It looks like this will work but correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Did you see my link ? AFAIK you can send a file to iDevice if there is a proper app on your device.

Comment: I think you should find a good app to do this job for you. Take a look at this one https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/fileapp-file-manager-document/id297804694?mt=8 Update: Also see this link http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49557/how-to-export-and-read-txt-files-using-iphone

Comment: Both your options look promising. I will try out and report back which one worked best for me! But really appreciate your help